# uso de rollback ante de hacer cambios en una tabla sql

Tags: sql-server

El rollback es para deshacer cambio en una tabla cuando se realiza una eliminación o actualización, mi pregunta es ¿Cómo es su uso para una actualización que deseo hacer?

Comment: ¿La "actualización" la haces desde el Management studio?

Answer (score 2):

En las bases de datos transaccionales, el ROLLBACK se utiliza para desechar las modificaciones realizadas dentro de una TRANSACTION (transacción).

Por ejemplo, en linea de comandos:

```
   UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1 WHERE...;   -- fuera de transac
   BEGIN;                                        -- abre transaction
   UPDATE t2 SET col1 = 3 WHERE... ;             -- dentro de transaction
   DELETE FROM t3 WHERE... ;                     -- 
   ...
   ROLLBACK;                                     -- deshace cambios desde BEGIN
```

En este ejemplo, la transacción se abre con el `BEGIN` (dependiendo de tu base de datos y tu API cliente eso puede variar). Las modificaciones que siguen formarán parte de esa transacción, se piensan como modificaciones "tentativas" que recién serán "realmente" grabadas (y, típicamente, serán visibles desde otras conexiones) cuando se confirme la transacción con un `COMMIT` . Si en lugar del COMMIT se ejecuta un ROLLBACK, entonces todas las modificaciones se deshacerán.

En el ejemplo, el primer `UPDATE t1...` se ejecuta fuera de la transacción, así que no es posible deshacer sus efectos con un ROLLBACK.

Esto es sólo una explicación básica, para más detalles (en referencia a SQL-server) puedes leer la documentación [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188929.aspx)